# jQuery Update Textarea without replacing content

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, textarea

In JavaScript you could just use the `=.` or `+=` to add *existing data* to data. How do I do this in jQuery. I am trying to add a check-box list to my form, each field should building up a list in the textarea separating data by a comma.

Can't seem to figure it. It just replaces the `q` value and does not add.

**jQuery**

```
function ExportButton(){
    var data = $('#orders').text();
    var selected = new Array();
        $('.mycb:checked').each(function() {
        var q = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(q);
        $('#orders').text(data+q+',');

    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><input type="checkbox" id="mycb2" class="mycb" value="Chocolate" /> Chocolate</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" id="mycb1" class="mycb" value="Vanilla" /> Vanilla</div>
<a href="javascript:ExportButton()">Export to Textarea</a>
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" id="orders" name="orders"></textarea>
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/GJXKW/3/

Any help would be appreciated. I want to a build a list like 4,5,3,4,24,2424,2, in the textarea ending without the comma would be a bonus but I will do regex maybe?

Comment: jQuery's `text()` method does not add content, it completely replaces it. Try `prepend()` or `append()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noone seems to recognize that this is inside a loop, and that `text()`, `html()` and `val()` will overwrite the content on each iteration. All you really have to do is concentenate the string in the loop, and append it once after the loop :

```
function ExportButton(){
  var data = "";

  $('.mycb:checked').each(function(i,el) {
      data += el.value + ',';
  });

  $('#orders').text( data );
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJXKW/7/)

Comment: +1 for detail and reading my question correctly. I added a blank liner to ensure the form is blank before running the function so that no data is ever duplicated.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid - You're welcome, and if you'd like to start with an empty textarea each time, just don't get it's value to begin with. I'll update the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val` instead of `.text` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJXKW/5/)

```
    function ExportButton(){
    var data;
    var selected = new Array();
        $('.mycb:checked').each(function() {
        var q = $(this).attr('value');  
            data = $('#orders').val();
            if(data ){
              data = data + "," +q 
            }else {
                  data = q 
            }
        $('#orders').val(data);

    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting to use an conditional statement so plus 1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because jQuery doesn't recognize the `text()` of a `<textarea>`. As it is like an input field, you may use the `val()` function:

```
function ExportButton(){
    var data = $('#orders').val();
    var selected = new Array();
    $('#mycb:checked').each(function() {
        var q = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(q);
        $('#orders').val(data+q+',');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a see at this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/GJXKW/8/

```
$('#export').click(function () {
    var checked = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        checked.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('textarea').val(checked.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always intermix jQuery and vanilla JS, so if you have something that works, just do it and don't call the overhead of jQuery for a simple text node append.

Comment: What are you talking about?